# String recource and attribute specification error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i just started with Java programing and Eclipse. I can't seem to get rid of these errors, anyone know how to fix it?

I'm following the "thenewboston" project.

I printed an image so you can see what's messing with me: http://www.ladda-upp.se/bilder/bwqzgrwlvjqusf/

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="45sp" 
    />  




<Button
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Add one"
    "android:id="@+id/bAdd"
     />

<Button
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text="Subtract one"
    android:textSeize="20sp" 
    android:id="@+id/bSub"/>
```

Comment: "android:id="@+id/bAdd" --- here seems to be an error. Remove the 1st " before android:

Answer (score 0):

Replace `"android:id="@+id/bAdd"` with `android:id="@+id/bAdd"`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Add one"
    "android:id="@+id/bAdd"
     />
```

To

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Add one"
    android:id="@+id/bAdd"
     />
```

Answer (score 0):

There's one syntax error:

```
"android:id="@+id/bAdd"
```

should remove the `"`from attribute name:

```
android:id="@+id/bAdd"
```

Then in

```
android:textSeize="20sp"
```

the attribute name should be `textSize`.

The remaining issues are lint warnings about hardcoded UI strings. You can ignore those at this phase of learning. (See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html later.)

Answer (score 0):

You have one error and two warning.
For Error remove first " from  "android:id="@+id/bAdd"
For two warning add "Add one" and "Subtract one" in strings.xml and provide the reference for the same here like - @string/add and @string/sub.